# Cisco ASA 5505 VPN users access to local LAN denied

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have this running config:

```
: Saved
:
ASA Version 8.2(5) 
!
hostname TESTATES
domain-name TEST.com
names
name 192.168.1.0 AsusWireless
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
dns domain-lookup inside
dns domain-lookup outside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name TEST.com
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_3
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_4
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_4
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_5
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_6
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_7
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_8
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_5
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_6
 network-object 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
 network-object xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_10
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
 protocol-object igrp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_9
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_11
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_12
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_13
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_14
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 any 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_8 xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 any 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_4 any object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_3 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_5 any xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_10 xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_6 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_13 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_14 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 interface inside 
access-list TUNNEL_LIST standard permit 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list TUNNEL_LIST standard permit 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_in extended permit ip 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 any 
access-list inside_out extended permit icmp any any log 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_3 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_4 any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_7 any xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2 any object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_6 xx.xx.xx.xx 255.255.255.248 any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit ip any any 
access-list outside_access_in extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_11 any 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_access_out extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_9 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_5 any 
access-list inside_access_out extended permit ip any any 
access-list inside_nat_outbound extended permit ip AsusWireless 255.255.255.0 any 
access-list inside_nat_outbound extended permit ip 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 any 
access-list outside_access_out extended permit ip any any 
access-list outside_access_out extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_12 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list MyTunnel standard permit 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 interface inside 
access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 172.16.16.0 255.255.255.0 any 
pager lines 24
logging console debugging
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
ip local pool VPN_CLIENTS 172.16.16.16-172.16.16.64 mask 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 access-list inside_nat_outbound
nat (inside) 1 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0
nat (inside) 1 AsusWireless 255.255.255.0
nat (outside) 0 access-list outside_nat0_outbound outside
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group inside_access_out out interface inside
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group outside_access_out out interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xx.xx.xx.xx 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
 description "AnyConnectACL"
 network-acl inside_in
 network-acl inside_out
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authentication telnet console LOCAL 
http server enable
http 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http AsusWireless 255.255.255.255 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto map inside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map inside_map interface inside
crypto isakmp enable inside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh AsusWireless 255.255.255.255 inside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
management-access inside
dhcp-client update dns server both
dhcpd address 172.16.1.5-172.16.1.36 inside
dhcpd dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 interface inside
dhcpd enable inside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
 enable inside
 enable outside
 anyconnect-essentials
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.05187-k9.pkg 1
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-linux-64-3.1.05187-k9.pkg 2
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-linux-3.1.05187-k9.pkg 3
 svc image disk0:/anyconnect-macosx-i386-3.1.05187-k9.pkg 4
 svc enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 dns-server value 172.16.1.2
 vpn-tunnel-protocol webvpn
 split-tunnel-network-list value TUNNEL_LIST
 split-tunnel-all-dns enable
 webvpn
  svc rekey method ssl
  svc compression deflate
group-policy GroupPolicy1 internal
group-policy GroupPolicy1 attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 172.16.1.2 8.8.4.4
 vpn-filter value inside_in
 vpn-tunnel-protocol IPSec l2tp-ipsec svc 
 group-lock value AnyConnectProfile
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value MyTunnel
 default-domain value TEST.com
tunnel-group AnyConnectProfile type remote-access
tunnel-group AnyConnectProfile general-attributes
 address-pool VPN_CLIENTS
 authorization-server-group LOCAL
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy1
tunnel-group AnyConnectProfile webvpn-attributes
 group-alias AnyConnectProfile enable
tunnel-group AnyConnectProfile ppp-attributes
 no authentication chap
 no authentication ms-chap-v1
 authentication ms-chap-v2
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect ip-options 
  inspect netbios 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect xdmcp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
no call-home reporting anonymous
call-home
 profile CiscoTAC-1
  no active
  destination address http https://tools.cisco.com/its/service/oddce/services/DDCEService
  destination address email callhome@cisco.com
  destination transport-method http
  subscribe-to-alert-group diagnostic
  subscribe-to-alert-group environment
  subscribe-to-alert-group inventory periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group configuration periodic monthly
  subscribe-to-alert-group telemetry periodic daily
Cryptochecksum:7094ec05e5882ead5a5dcc5faaf278c3
: end
asdm location AsusWireless 255.255.255.0 inside
no asdm history enable
```

When people login through VPN, they get IP addresses such as 172.16.16.6
I want them to access local LAN at computers such as 172.16.1.9

But it's not working and packet tracer confirms that it's not working:

[image: packet tracer output]

It says it's something with the NAT, but I don't know what's wrong with NAT rules. Please advise

Comment: "It says it's something with the NAT," sounds like pretty relevant info to include in the question.

Comment: @gparent, I've included entire configuration and NAT settings

Comment: But not what your ASA *says about the NAT*

Comment: @gparent, http://i.stack.imgur.com/zXr8b.png

Comment: Perfect. I included it in the question. Would it be possible to do this via the command-line so that it is readable and maybe more familiar to ASA users?

Comment: @gparent, I'm not really familiar with command line and I use ASDM for everything

Comment: Alright. I'm no expert on ASA so I don't have a solution, but your output above is telling you that you don't have any rules configured to allow traffic to go to that network.